# How to use the if else conditional loop?

Tags: reactjs, loops, if-statement, printing

I need some help in this conditional code.
In order to store the required data to the variable `paw`, I have three conditions.

1. If `nameu` is not blank or empty and `empidu` is blank or empty, it should store the `Title : nameu` only.
2. Else if `nameu` is blank or empty and `empidu` is not blank or empty, it should store the `EmpID : empidu` only.
3. Else store both.

I have written the code myself, but it is not working. Here is the code :

```
var paw = "";
    if(nameu !== " ") {
       paw = JSON.stringify({
        Title: nameu
      });
    }
    else if(nameu === "" & empidu !== " ") {
       paw = JSON.stringify({
        EmpID: empidu
      });
    }
    else {
     paw = JSON.stringify({
      Title: nameu,
      EmpID: empidu,
    });
  }
```

> Note : nameu (String) and empidu (number) are user input values

I think I am either writing wrong statements or logic. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use logical AND operator (&&) to evaluate multiple expressions instead of bitwise AND (&)

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use this code

```js
    let paw = {};
    if (nameu.trim() !== ''){
       paw.Title=nameu;
    }
    if (empidu.trim() !== ''){
       paw.EmpID = empidu;
    }
    paw = JSON.stringify(paw);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But adding && worked for me. Here is the code :
`var paw = "";
    if(nameu !== " " && empidu === "") {
       paw = JSON.stringify({
        Title: nameu
      });
    }
    else if(nameu === "" && empidu !== " ") {
       paw = JSON.stringify({
        EmpID: empidu
      });
    }
    else {
     paw = JSON.stringify({
      Title: nameu,
      EmpID: empidu,
    });
  }`

Comment: It's really good but you can improve your code and maintainable
happy coding!